# How to put sever in debug mode by using ANT script

Tags: ant, weblogic

I am able to start Weblogic server by using ANT i need to start this server now in debug mode,
plz help

used following script for starting server.

```
 <target name="startserver" depends="stopserver">
        <wlserver dir="${domain.home}/${domain.name}" host="${host}" port="${port}" domainname="${domain.name}"
                  servername="${admin.server.name}" action="start" username="${username}" password="${password}"
                  beahome="${bea.home}" weblogichome="${weblogic.home}" verbose="true" noexit="true" protocol="t3"
                  classpath="${weblogic.home}/server/lib/weblogic.jar">
            <jvmarg value="-server"/>
            <jvmarg value="-Xms256m"/>
            <jvmarg value="-Xmx512m"/>
            <jvmarg value="-XX:PermSize=128m"/>
            <jvmarg value="-XX:MaxPermSize=256m"/>
        </wlserver>
    </target>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following jvmarg in the ant task.

```
-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8473,server=y,suspend=n -Djava.compiler=NONE
```

Comment: hi can you tell how to restart weblogic server using ant task ?